# Как сделать текст внутри полупрозрачного Div'а непрозрачным?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать текст внутри полупрозрачного Div'а непрорачным?

Нужно привести к такому виду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
div.image6 {
  background: url("../img/menu/6.jpg") 100% 100% no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 275px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  opacity: 0.4;
  &:hover {
    transition: 0.25s;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

div.shadow {
  background-color: #000;
  p {
    color: red;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```
        <div class="shadow">
            <div class="image1">
                <p>#<span>1</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="image2">
                <p>#<span>2</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="image3">
                <p>#<span>3</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

При наведении на данный блок с текстом, текст и затемнение должно пропадать, то есть остается одна картинка полностью непрозрачная.

Comment: **Если контейнер имеет прозрачность, то его все вложенные элементы будут прозрачными.** Как-то отменить это свойство нельзя!! но можно сделать немного иначе:
Сделал некоторые наброски: https://vk.cc/6XW404

Answer (score 3):

Со свойством `opacity` никак.
Используйте комбинацию `background-image` и `background-color: rgba()`

Answer (score 0):

Поместите текст в отдельный div, укажите ему абсолютное позиционирование и бОльший приоритет, чем у дива с картинкой с помощью свойства z-index

http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index

Comment: Мне казалось, что `opacity` действует на все дочерние элементы контейнера без исключения и возможности сброса.

Comment: Тут ещё такой момент, я хочу чтобы при наведении, затемнение вместе с текстом становилось либо просто прозрачным, либо Display: none

Comment: ну обоим дивам устанавливайте display: none при нужном событии

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, да, я почему-то сначала подумал, что очевидно выделить текст и картинку в разные блоки